# Riemann integrable space

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Is it possible to prove that $(\Re_{[a,b]},d_i)$ the space of integrable Riemann functions ,with the integral metric ($d_i$), is complete? I have stumbled upon a proof that makes use of Cantor set but I cannot understand the intuition behind the fact that $(\Re_{[a,b]},d_i)$ is incomplete. Is there any completion? What does completion mean? Thanks!

Comment: What's $d_i{}$?

Comment: What do you mean by the integral metric?

Comment: $d_i=\int \left| f -g\right|dx$

Answer (score 1):

No. There are differentiable functions on closed intervals, given by series, whose derivatives are not Riemann integrable (Volterra and Pompeiu both constructed such functions). Thus, the partial sums will be a Cauchy sequence in the $d_1$ metric, but the limit function is not Riemann integrable.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_n\colon[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ be defined as $$f_n(x)=\min\Bigl(\frac{1}{\sqrt x},n\Bigr).$$
If $m<n$ then
$$
\int_0^1|f_m(x)-f_n(x)|\,dx=\int_{0}^{1/n^2}(n-m)\,dx+\int_{1/n^2}^{1/m^2}\Bigl(\frac{1}{\sqrt x}-m\Bigr)\,dx=\frac1m-\frac1n.
$$
$\{f_n\}$ is Cauchy, but its limit is unbounded, and hence not Riemann integrable.

The completion is the space $L^1$ of Lebesgue integrable functions.

Comment: I am acquainted with that example. But acoording to Principles of mathematical analasys $\int f d\alpha=lim_(n\in\mathbb{N})\int f_n d\alpha$. Why does it diverge? Is there a general proof that shows this divergence for every function?